# UITests Post Failed in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a fresh Xmarain.Forms project and a fresh Xmarain.Forms UI Tests project. I've managed to get the freshly created Android apk built and installed to my emulated device.

My Unit Tests application is able to connect to the installed apk. When it attempts to run the first test I get the following error though:

```
System.Net.WebException : POST Failed
   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.HandleHttpError(String method, HttpResponseMessage response, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.SendData(String endpoint, String method, HttpContent content, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.Post(String endpoint, String arguments, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.HttpApplicationStarter.Execute(String intentJson)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp(String appPackageName, ApkFile testServerApkFile, Int32 testServerPort)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, IExecutor executor)
   at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
   at New.Mobile.Tests.AppTests.BeforeEachTest()
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is pretty basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.New.Mobile" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<application android:label="New.Mobile.Android" 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I don't even have any http calls in my app. What gives?
How do you even begin to debug something like this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I created the project in Visual studio as Xamarin UI test project. Any working solution?

Comment: @UbaidRana did you try the answer I have aded?

Comment: Yes, but I already created the project in Visual Studio, so it doesn't apply in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the Test Project was created in Rider. Creating the Test project in visual studio allows you to progress beyond this error.