# Xamarin UITest for Android: POST Failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

With my project upon running UI Tests I get `POST Failed` error. I can't figure what is the cause of the problem. [UITests Post Failed in Xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57895653), related to the same issue did not help.

On an actual device I get `Instrumentation backend` app installed (it runs as a server for UI Tests). But I am still getting `POST Failed` error.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the Android OS version.

`Instrumentation backend` application does not work properly on new android os-es.

I created a simulator with older Android OS (Android 6.0 Marshmallow).

**And ran UITests with this simulator selected in Visual Studio**.

And all things worked.

Hope it will help someone who struggles with the same issue.

Old school things are better than new ones.